# How can I wrap RadioButtonGroup's label? Where can i give Expanded or Flexible?

Tags: flutter, word-wrap, radio-group, expander, flexible-type

In this project I have 10 questions and each questions have 4 options. each option is overflowing(flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 196 pixels on the right.
). See My code below

```
//using RadioButtonGroup because question have 4 option
 RadioButtonGroup(
   labels: <String>[
     que_list[index]['option_list'][0],
     que_list[index]['option_list'][1],
     que_list[index]['option_list'][2],
     que_list[index]['option_list'][3]
   ],
   labelStyle: TextStyle(
     fontSize: 15,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
     color: Colors.white
   ),
   onChange: (String label, int index) {},
   onSelected: (String selected) {
     print(selected);
   },
   activeColor: Colors.white,
 ),
```

I tried above code and also give Column and Container to the `RadioButtonGroup` but no change occurs. Can anyone help me sort this out?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by overflowing?

Comment: flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 196 pixels on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      child: RadioButtonGroup(
        labels: <String>[
          "que_list[index]['option_list'][0] que_list[index]['option_list'][0]",
          "que_list[index]['option_list'][1]",
          "que_list[index]['option_list'][2]",
          "que_list[index]['option_list'][3]"
        ],
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            color: Colors.white),
        onChange: (String label, int index) {},
        onSelected: (String selected) {
          print(selected);
        },
        activeColor: Colors.white,
          itemBuilder: (Radio radioButton, Text label, int index) {
            return Row(children: [radioButton, Flexible(child: label)]);
          }
      )),
    ));
```

[image]

Comment: @PRASHANTKARELIYA , I have updated my response, please recheck and let me know what else would be of interest.

Comment: if you can please also mark as answer (not just upvote). Thanks